# find nearest number in list of float

Tags: c#, arrays, find

hi there i have an list of float

```
       List<float> distance = new List<float>();
        distance.Add(66.2F);
        distance.Add(69.9F);
        distance.Add(70.2F);
        distance.Add(70.3F);
        distance.Add(70.6F);
        distance.Add(71.4F);
        distance.Add(71.6F);
```

i have a extension method which get nearest number from this array

```
 public static class extenstions
{
    public static float ClosestTo(this IEnumerable<float> collection, float target)
    {

        var closest = float.MaxValue;
        var minDifference = float.MaxValue;
        foreach (var element in collection)
        {
            var difference = Math.Abs((long)element - target);
            if (minDifference > difference)
            {
                minDifference = (int)difference;
                closest = element;
            }
        }

        return closest;
    }
}
```

float closest = distance.ClosestTo(70F);
now if i want to find nearest of number 70 it will return 70.2 what i want is to modify this function to return less closest  69.9 instead of higher value 70.2.
can you help?

Comment: Why do you cast `element` to `long`? That doesn't make sense providing you work with floating point numbers everywhere.

Comment: Just removing that cast to `long` would work

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, no, you also need to remove the cast to int...

Answer (score 4):

Using Linq:

```
public static float ClosestTo(this IEnumerable<float> collection, float target)
{
    return collection.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(target - x)).First();
}
```

Or, using the [`MinBy`](http://thomaslevesque.github.io/Linq.Extras/doc/html/M_Linq_Extras_XEnumerable_MinBy__2.htm) extension method from [Linq.Extras](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/Linq.Extras):

```
public static float ClosestTo(this IEnumerable<float> collection, float target)
{
    return collection.MinBy(x => Math.Abs(target - x));
}
```

It's better than using `OrderBy` because it runs in `O(n)` instead of `O(n log n)`.

---

EDIT: if two numbers are equally close to the target and you want the greater of the two, you can do this:

```
public static float ClosestTo(this IEnumerable<float> collection, float target)
{
    return collection
        .OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(target - x))
        .ThenByDescending(x => x)
        .First();
}
```

Comment: hi what if i have this values
69.9 70.1
and i want to return closest it returns 69.9 i would like to get 70.1???
so if call closestto(70) it return 69.9 can we tweek it to return 70.1???

Comment: @IkramKhan, based on what criteria would you select 70.1 rather than 69.9?

Comment: actually will it be possible to passin functiona either we want to get less cloasest number to target or greater cloasest number to target??

Comment: Look at my comment maybe this will be helpful i edit it

Answer (score 2):

Probably when u cast value to long u lose number after coma 70,2 -> 70 and 69,9 -> 69 and 70 is closest to 70 than 69

If u want to take closest from left or right use this :

```
    public static float ClosestTo(this IEnumerable<float> collection, float target)
    {
        float a = collection.Where(x => x >= target).OrderBy(x => x - target).First();
        float b = collection.Where(x => x < target).OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(target - x)).First();
        return a.Equals(b) ? a : Math.Min(a, b);
    }
```

where `a` is right and `b` is left ( if u wanna left change `return a.Equals(b) ? a : Math.Min(a, b);` to `return a.Equals(b) ? b : Math.Min(a, b);`

Comment: that is helpful thanks i come up with this as per my requirements
leftdistance= target-b;
rightdistace=a-target;
if(leftdistance==rightdistance)
{return a;}
elseif leftdistache<rightdistance{b;}
else{ return a;}

Answer (score 1):

Do not cast the *element* variable to long.